# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} not working as intended

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new to url rewriting, i have a url say *xyz.com/product.php?id=23* which i want to get redirected to *xyz.com/brand/brandname*

I've spent the whole day trying different permutations and combinations for RewriteCond and RewriteRule but all in vain.

Comment: Please post what some of you've attempted so far.

Comment: as @pgl says, please show us what you have so far. Also, please be a bit more specific with what you're trying to achieve; is `/brand/` a static value? How does `brandname` relate to `id=23`? Do you have fixed values for it that you're planning to write into your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} product.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=23
RewriteRule . /brand/brandname? [R=301,L]
```

But i think that you must to it via php. For example, if on old page id=23 is a brand Apple. In product.php:

```
mysql_query("select name from brands where id="intval($_GET['id']));
...
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: /brand/'.$brand['name']);
```